# initialize a bluetooth connection between Android (server) and bluecove on pc (client)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I know there are other topics about that but in my case I want the Android device to initialize the bluetooth connection as a server. I followed the Documentation and I wrote the server in this way:

```
private class AcceptThread implements Runnable {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {

        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = mBluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                    "myService", mUuid);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("SERVER SOCKET LISTENING");
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                System.out.println("SIGNAL RECEIVED");
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SIGNAL RECEIVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    mmServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

On the other side I have bluecove API that discover remote devices and services.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.bluetooth.DeviceClass;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryListener;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.ServiceRecord;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;

/**
* A simple SPP client that connects with an SPP server
*/
public class SampleSPPClient implements DiscoveryListener{

    //object used for waiting
    private static Object lock=new Object();

    //vector containing the devices discovered
    private static Vector vecDevices=new Vector();

    private static String connectionURL=null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SampleSPPClient client=new SampleSPPClient();

        //display local device address and name
        LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        System.out.println("Address: "+localDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
        System.out.println("Name: "+localDevice.getFriendlyName());

        //find devices
        DiscoveryAgent agent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();

        System.out.println("Starting device inquiry...");
        agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, client);

        try {
            synchronized(lock){
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Device Inquiry Completed. ");

        //print all devices in vecDevices
        int deviceCount=vecDevices.size();

        if(deviceCount <= 0){
            System.out.println("No Devices Found .");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            //print bluetooth device addresses and names in the format [ No. address (name) ]
            System.out.println("Bluetooth Devices: ");
            for (int i = 0; i <deviceCount; i++) {
                RemoteDevice remoteDevice=(RemoteDevice)vecDevices.elementAt(i);
                System.out.println((i+1)+". "+remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress()+" ("+remoteDevice.getFriendlyName(true)+")");
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Choose Device index: ");
        BufferedReader bReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String chosenIndex=bReader.readLine();
        int index=Integer.parseInt(chosenIndex.trim());

        //check for spp service
        RemoteDevice remoteDevice=(RemoteDevice)vecDevices.elementAt(index-1);
        UUID[] uuidSet = new UUID[1];
        uuidSet[0]=new UUID("4e3aea40e2a511e095720800200c9a66", false);

        System.out.println("\nSearching for service...");
        agent.searchServices(null,uuidSet,remoteDevice,client);

        try {
            synchronized(lock){
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(connectionURL==null){
            System.out.println("Device does not support Simple SPP Service.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //connect to the server and send a line of text
        StreamConnection streamConnection=(StreamConnection)Connector.open(connectionURL);

        //send string
        OutputStream outStream=streamConnection.openOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pWriter=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outStream));
        pWriter.write("Test String from SPP Client\r\n");
        pWriter.flush();


        //read response
        InputStream inStream=streamConnection.openInputStream();
        BufferedReader bReader2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        String lineRead=bReader2.readLine();
        System.out.println(lineRead);


    }//main

    //methods of DiscoveryListener
    public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
        //add the device to the vector
        if(!vecDevices.contains(btDevice)){
            vecDevices.addElement(btDevice);
        }
    }

    //implement this method since services are not being discovered
    public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
        System.out.println(servRecord[0].getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false));
        if(servRecord!=null && servRecord.length>0){
            connectionURL=servRecord[0].getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.AUTHENTICATE_ENCRYPT,false);
        }
        synchronized(lock){
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    //implement this method since services are not being discovered
    public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
        synchronized(lock){
            lock.notify();
        }
    }


    public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
        synchronized(lock){
            lock.notify();
        }

    }//end method



}
```

The client found the device and the service but when retrieve the url from the ServiceRecord to establish the connection it fails. It retrieve an Url in which the channel is wrong and it throws an exception: javax.bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionException: Failed to connect;

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find some phone ServiceRecords when using:

```
    UUID[] uuidSet = new UUID[1];
    uuidSet[0]=new UUID(0x0100);
    int[] attrIds = { 0x0100 };

    System.out.println("\nSearching for service...");
    agent.searchServices(attrIds, uuidSet, remoteDevice, client);
```

And you will be calling lock.notify() twice after a serviceSearch, remove it in the servicesDiscovered function.

You should also go through the service records and look for the one you are interested in. The URL will state btgoep:// or btspp://

When searching through the for loop use this code to list the service name

```
 for(int i = 0; i < servRecord.length; i++)
 {
    String url = servRecord[i].getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);
    DataElement serviceName = srs[i].getAttributeValue(0x0100);
    if (serviceName != null) {
       System.out.println("service " + serviceName.getValue() + " found " + url);
    } else {
       System.out.println("service found " + url);
    }
```

I have the exact problem, it seems like the android api doesn't register the ServiceRecord with the SDP so the Bluecove api can find it.
No matter what UUID I use it will only find the ones my phone register as default, i e Audio gateways and Phonebook OBEX push and such.

EDIT ---
I had the same problem, but realized I had not actually called listenUsingInsecureRFCOMMSocket yet. And then it did not register the service record.
But after that it worked just fine.